# Firebase Rules to allow users to block other users from reading their data

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am working on a social media app where users can follow other users. I need to incorporate a block user feature.

If User A blocks User B, then User B is not allowed to look at User A's profile, and read their data. Same functionality as blocking users on Instagram and Facebook. I think I am getting close, but I have set up a node on Firebase that adds blocked users.

In the case of User A and User B, the database looks like this:

> -blockedUser: 
>   ---User A: 
>   ------User B: true

```
Database.database().reference().child("blockedUser").child(currentUserId).child(userToBlock).setValue(true)
```

> So that is how my database is set up, these are how my rules look:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$user_id": {
        "$blockedID" : {
            ".read": "auth != null && !root.child('blockedUser/'+$user_id+'/'+$blockedID+'/true').exists()",
           ".write": "$user_id === auth.uid"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The issue I'm having is with the rules. In terms of User A and User B, once User B is blocked, it prevents User B from reading any data on the database. What I am trying to achieve is when User B is blocked by User A, then it should prevent User B from reading ONLY User A's Data. How can I adjust my rules to do this?

Comment: Can you try using `!data.child(auth.uid).exists()` under `$user_id` instead of `root.child(...`?

Answer (score 0):

With you approach, you are preventing User B from reading the field containing the blocking information. What you want is apply the rule on another hierarchic level. By using auth.uid (in your scenario User B), you can prevent the current User from reading any data of a specific User (in your scenario User A).

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$user_id": {
        ".read": "auth != null && !root.child('users').child($user_id).child(auth.uid).exists()",
        "$blockedID" : {
           ".write": "$user_id === auth.uid"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is still not working, User B is still not allowed to read any data on the database itself.

Comment: You mean, he is not allowed to read any other data somewhere else in the database?

Comment: Yes, the feature should function where he is not allowed to read the data of the user he's blocked from, but instead it is functioning where he is not allowed to read any data from all users in the database.

Comment: Then you must have some rule preventing anyone to read somewhere in your ruleset. If you don't provide any specific rule, all read and write access is allowed. Are you sure, you can read the data before you are blocked ?